# How to get the value of the image when clickin

Tags: javascript, php, input

How to get the value of the image for us it on `$_POST`

```
$url_f = $crawler->filter('#content .galleries_overview .item')->each(function(crawler $node, $i) {
 //echo $node->html();
    $image = $node->filter('img')->attr('src');
    $src = $node->filter('a')->attr('href');
    $href = 'https://example.com/'. $src;
?>
<input type="image" name="submit_blue" value="<?php echo $href ?>" src="<?php echo $image ?>">

<?php

 }); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use onclick

```
<input type="image" onclick="sendme('<?php echo $href ?>')" src="<?php echo $image ?>">
```

and add this to your page :

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
<input type="hidden" name="submit_blue" id="submit_blue" value="" >
</form>
<script>
function sendme(x) {
    document.getElementById("submit_blue").value = x;
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
</script>
```

that is a javascript solution i use if i do not want to use jquery or something

By the way I don't like using URL as a value